# How to convert a tibble to datatable and which syntax to use?

Tags: r, data.table

I've got this huge dataset (tibble):

```
DF <- tibble::tribble(
  ~ID, ~D_OPR, ~C_OPR,
   1L,     NA, "ABCD",
   1L, "ABCD",     NA,
   1L,     NA,     NA,
   2L,     NA,     NA
  )
```

The desired output is:

```
     ID D_OPR C_OPR  ALFA
  <int> <chr> <chr> <int>
1     1 NA    ABCD      1
2     1 ABCD  NA        1
3     1 NA    NA        1
4     3 NA    NA        0
```

To achieve this I use the following code:

```
library(tidyverse)

BETA <- c("ABCD", "EDFGH")

DF <- DF %>%
  group_by(ID) %>%
  mutate(ALFA = case_when(grepl(paste0(BETA, collapse = "|"), D_OPR) | grepl(paste0(BETA, collapse = "|"), C_OPR) ~ 1, TRUE ~ 0)) %>%
  fill(ALFA, .direction = "updown")

DF <- DF %>%
  group_by(ID) %>%
  mutate(ALFA = max(ALFA, na.rm = T))
```

To get a faster process time I want to convert the tibble to a `data.table` but I have no idea about the syntax. Anybody knows?

Comment: Maybe take a look [here](https://github.com/tidyverse/dtplyr)

Comment: see `setDT()`. For example you use `setDT(DF)`.
However you must load `library(data.table)` before

Comment: You should also read `vignette('datatable-intro')`

Comment: Note that making it a `data.table` itself is not giving you the speed gain when you still going to do your operations with non-data.table functions and operations.

Comment: Merjin: But, that is my question. How do I translate my non-data.table functions and operations to data.table functions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We may use `Reduce`

```
library(data.table)
setDT(DF)[,  ALPHA := max(Reduce(`+`, lapply(.SD, `%chin%`, BETA))), by = ID]
```

-output

```
> DF
   ID D_OPR C_OPR ALPHA
1:  1  <NA>  ABCD     1
2:  1  ABCD  <NA>     1
3:  1  <NA>  <NA>     1
4:  2  <NA>  <NA>     0
```

---

Or may also do

```
setDT(DF)[, ALPHA := max(BETA %chin% unlist(.SD)), ID]
```

Answer (score 3):

As you are new to `data.table` I strongly advice to study the documentation and get a grip on the basics of the syntax. It has a bit higher learning curve than `dplyr` and might look less intuitive, however it is pretty straightforward when you practice a lot.

https://search.r-project.org/CRAN/refmans/data.table/html/data.table.html

**data.table conversion of your request**

```
library(data.table)
setDT(DF)

BETA <- c("ABCD", "EDFGH")

DF[, ALPHA := max(apply(.SD, 1, \(x) any(x %in% BETA))), .SDcols = 2:3, by = ID]
```

**results**

```
   ID D_OPR C_OPR ALPHA
1:  1  <NA>  ABCD     1
2:  1  ABCD  <NA>     1
3:  1  <NA>  <NA>     1
4:  2  <NA>  <NA>     0
```

Answer (score 1):

You could solve your problem using data.table as follow:

```
library(data.table)
setDT(DF)

DF[, ALPHA := +any(BETA %chin% c(D_OPR, C_OPR)), by=ID]

      ID  D_OPR  C_OPR ALPHA
1:     1   <NA>   ABCD     1
2:     1   ABCD   <NA>     1
3:     1   <NA>   <NA>     1
4:     2   <NA>   <NA>     0
```

Note the use of `%chin%` instead of `%in%` for faster speed.

Comment: Thanks, very elegant solution. However, let´s say I change the DF (D_OPR and C_OPR) to "ABCD1" or "ABCD123" - then I still want it to count as TRUE (because it starts with ABCD as defined in BETA). Any solution to that? :)